# Using tfrupee with texlive in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have full TeXlive.

I wanted Indian rupee symbol. I downloaded [`tfrupee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tfrupee) from CTAN. I did following:

```
unzip tfrupee.zip  
cd tfrupee/  
sudo cp -rv fonts/type1/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/  
sudo cp -rv fonts/afm/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/afm/  
sudo cp -rv fonts/tfm/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/  
sudo cp -rv fonts/map/dvips/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/  
sudo cp -rv fonts/source/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/  
sudo cp -rv tex/latex/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/  
sudo texhash  
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=tfrupee.map
```

Now, Kile recognizes `tfrupee` package, but it does not recognize `\rupee` symbol.

Please help.

Comment: Try with `updmap-sys --enable Map newfont.map`. (without =)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. Also, you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I tried updmap-sys --enable Map newfont.map. but failed...

Comment: i think Torbjørn T. meant "newfont" to be an example.  in your case, that example would signify "updmap-sys --enable Map tfrupee.map"

Comment: Yes had tried updmap-sys --enable Map tfrupee.map

Comment: Workaround with TikZ `\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\newrupee}[1][0.02]
{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
  \fill (0,0) -- (2,0)  arc(270:450:4 and 3) -- (0,6) -- (0.5,6.5) -- (2,6.5) arc(90:-90:5 and 3.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- cycle;
  \fill (0,6) -- (0.5,6.5) -- (8.5,6.5)-- (8,6) -- cycle;
  \fill (0,3) -- (0.5,3.5) -- (8.5,3.5)-- (8,3) -- cycle;
  \fill (0,-0.5) -- (1.5,-0.5) -- (6.5,-7) -- (5,-7) -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \xspace
}`